Are minors required to be represented by an attorney in Kentucky?
I was in court with my child on a truancy case and was told by the judge that a minor in the State of Kentucky is required by state law to have representation by an attorney.
What does Kentucky law say about minors requiring legal representation?

As opposed to representing themselves? Or having a parent/guardian represent them?

@Barmar, seems like yes...  because those are really the only other reasonable options, right?

@MichaelHall My point is whether a lawyer is required even if they have their parent with them.

I don't see why this would be inaccurate. In general, people are advised not to represent themselves in court. And minors generally have fewer rights than adults. I don't see why they wouldn't prohibit children from representing themselves.

@"My point is whether a lawyer is required even if they have their parent with them."  That's precisely what the question would appear to be asking...

I just edited to clarify what I believe is the most accurate interpretation.  Sgt, please let me know if this is correct.  And Semper Fi...

Thanks everyone here is the short story. My kids are 17 they have  shown up a min or two late for school 18 times over the last year. Probably because they stand in the hall and talk to their friends but whatever that’s the issue.
3 tardies even a minute late counts as an absence, 9 absences count as habitually truant. When I say they missed a total of 49 mins of class over the year that is no exaggeration.
I am not willing to comply with deferment on principle. Now we are heading to court. I am the one charged but the judge said the kids require an attorney.

I really don’t feel like this is true. Kentucky CPS has a terrible track record and I am probably going to lose but I am going to fight them.
The kids are also passing class, drug free etc… so I feel like this is a massive waste of government resources.i was a tanker so I am not that smart but I am not backing down.
